# Flourescent bulb problem

Tags: electrical

I have a 4 bulb fixture in my kitchen.I turned the lights and only 2 appeared to be lighting and they were very weak. The 2 outside bulbs had black on the ends, so I replaced them. They came on very weak, and the 2 middles were about the same. Fiddled with new bulbs and they came on full power but the middle 2 shut off completely. If I turn off the lights, and turn them back on, all four come on but barely create any light. What's going on with this?

Comment: Would try replacing the two middle ones.  If that does fix the problem, the ballast might be going and need replacement also.

Comment: You had two mostly dead bulbs and two completely dead bulbs, yet you only replaced two bulbs. 2 more new bulbs is certainly the first and simplest thing to try, here.

Comment: These days, just replace with LEDs, but if a regular tube is black at the ends, change the tube *and the starter*. As the tube dies, it takes the starter down with it, by making it fire much more than normal, shortening its life considerably.

Comment: There are a lot of specifics to "just replace a fluorescent with an LED". There are several _long_ answers on the different types of replacement bulbs available and the efforts and pros/cons of each type.

Comment: @FreeMan - of course - mainly I wanted to point out the necessity of also changing the starters if you change a regular fluorescent tube.

Answer (score 5):

This is usually caused by a bad ballast. The ballast is a rectangular black box located in the fixture above the bulbs. You might have to remove a white metal cover above the bulbs to expose the ballast. After turning off the power, remove the ballast by unscrewing the screws holding it in place and cut the wires a few inches away from the ballast. The feed wires can be removed just by removing the wire nuts. Take the ballast to your home store or your electrical supply store for a replacement. Screw the ballast into the fixture and connect the feed wires to the black and white wires from the ballast with the wire nuts. You'll need additional small   wire nuts, usually blue, to connect the other ballast wires to the ones you cut earlier. There's a nice diagram right on the ballast if you've got questions.

Comment: @TomSmith There are also many fluorescent-fixture replacement LED fixtures available now; perhaps this is a good opportunity to upgrade.

Comment: @Armand  That's a good point.

Answer (score 1):

There are LED replacement tubes (bulbs), some maintain the need for a ballast, others simply run on 120v.  For the 120v versions, you remove the ballast and starter if so equipped and re-wire according to the instructions. The wiring is actually much simplified.  You are required to place a sticker (included with tubes) on the fixture saying something to the effect of "no ballast, use only 120v tubes" or something like that to make sure nobody tries to use high voltage LED (or normal florescent tubes) in the fixture.

If your ballast is bad and you don't go with the 120v tubes, you'll still have to replace it, which seems like a waste.

Of course if your existing fixtures are ugly and you want to replace them, like Armand said, now would be a good time.

I rebuilt a flourscent art decco fixture for my mom a few years ago, it was beatiful, no way could it be replaced given the period of the house. It's really a simple matter, these aren't rocket science.